# How can I specify a different default target for building and testing in the Cargo config?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm cross-compiling a Rust bare metal application for AArch64 target and I need to run unit tests on x86_64 target (my PC).

I created the file `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
target = "aarch64-unknown-none"
```

I'd like to build for AArch64 but to run the tests for x86_64. If I change the build to `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` then the tests compile and execute. Is there a section where I could specify this? I have to swap these manually now.

I checked [cargo guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) but found no reference about test configuration.

Comment: I assume you mean that it has to be default (I've updated your title on that assumption). Otherwise, you can just do `cargo test --target=...`

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, this works - I put it into Makefile.toml file. Though I was interested if it's possible to specify this in Cargo config file rather than pass it as an input param.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve similar functionality by creating an alias in your .cargo/config file

```
[alias]
test_pc = "test --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
```

then, you just just call

```
cargo test_pc
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

According to [issue#6874](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6784), cargo doesn't have the feature to specify different target for `cargo test`.

FYI: you might have another solution for this issue if you use `nightly`, though I haven't made it work. The following links are about `custom test framework`, the issue opener says 'the solution'.

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/53410
- https://blog.jrenner.net/rust/testing/2018/08/06/custom-test-framework-prop.html